# Openshift and CloudFlare (Website wp-admin redirect too many times)

Tags: loops, redirect, openshift, root, cloudflare

I got this redirect loop when I want to go to admin page. However the standard webpages works. Ever since I using cloudflare I can't go to the domain.com/wp-admin page.

In the openshift setting, I added alias then I added cname in cloudflare.

What should I do? It mentions something like domain root. What is it? I tried added the ip which I ping from the domain.rhcloud.com.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [CloudFlare's Flexible SSL](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-) offering, by any chance?

If so, it could be a [redirect loop because the Origin server cannot correctly identify what protocol the client is connecting over](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-).

In this situation my recommendation would be to install the [CloudFlare Flexible SSL WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cloudflare-flexible-ssl/).

Essentially; as the HTTPS request is terminated at CloudFlare, and passed through to the Origin in HTTP the origin will never be satisfied that the connection is over HTTPS and constantly redirects the user to the HTTPS site. The CloudFlare Flexible SSL Plugin utilises the X-Forwarded-Proto header to determine the correct protocol between the end-user and CloudFlare.

[image: CloudFlare SSL Options]

Answer (score 0):

You should try excluding the /wp-admin path in your cloudflare settings.  There is really no reason that the admin interface should go through a CDN.  You could also check your settings in wp-config.php and make sure that force ssl is not set, as the traffic between cloudflare and your gear is probably not encypted, and it keeps trying to encrypt it with that setting.